# Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::users does not exist. Dashboard problem registered

Tags: php, roles, dashboard, laravel-9

I am a beginner on Laravel and I am trying to improve.
I am trying to create a blog with 3 differents Roles.

I have a problem displaying my user's dashboard when registered. Apparently the *users()* method does not exist but it does exist in my **role model**.

screen of the error

[image: screen of the error]

database screen

[image: database screen]

**role model**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function role(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
@if(Auth::users()->role->libelle =='admin');
    @include('roles.admin')
@elsif(Auth::users()->role->libelle =='trainer');
    @include('roles.trainer')
@elsif(Auth::users()->role->libelle =='user');
    @include('roles.user')
@endif
```

**user.blade.php**

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                    You're logged in as user!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Comment: Laravel's authenticated user is `Auth::user()`, not `Auth::users()`

Comment: `@elsif` should be `@elseif`

Comment: Please include your errors as text instead of an image